# how to use facebook login to access data from server in android application

Tags: android

I want to use Facebook Login into my Android app,So that user can access the data from server.
Here I am using Drupal services.

Firstly user enter the username and password then it would verify on Facebook.Then if the user is authentic then it should access his data from drupal services module.
I don't know here that how my server would know that user is authentic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when first time user login using facebook, register that user on your server with his mail-id if mail-id does not exits on your server otherwise proceed with the user info, then give him the authentication key to access your web services,

Place a facebook Login Button in your app, after clicking the facbook button if user get authentication from Facebook, get the Facebook mail id, name, etc from `GraphUser`, now you got all the info on your mobile, now make a request to your own server with these parameters and check whether a user already exits with same credentials (like email id), if exist then then give him the authenticated token, other wise register that user in your db and then give him the authentication token. is that clear now

Comment: Kapil can you elaborate this that how I have to do this work.I have already connected my android app with facebook but the main thing is that how I can autheticate the user on my server using facebook login.

Comment: Ok kapil means that if user already registered with db then automatically an authentication token is generated and access is given to the user.But I want to know that how I can generate an authentication token on server.Sorry may be this is my foolish question but I really have no idea of how to generate the authentication token.....

Comment: Hi kapil,Please tell me how I can generate the authentication token on server that would verify the user...

Comment: kapil can you provide some code of how to generate authentication token.I am really stuck at this point please help me

Comment: that is server side implementation, which framework you are using on server side

Comment: Write now I am using Drupal web services. As the site for which I am making application is based on Drupal.